# How does one parse weather data?

Tags: data-request, weather, noaa, parsing

Weather data is often cited as a "huge success" for the open data community. Where does this data sit, and how does one parse the data into something readable, like the 5 day forecast?

Comment: You should try [GRIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) data format for yourself. [zyGRIB](http://www.zygrib.org/) is possibly the best entry-level application to explore weather forecast fields.

Answer (score 7):

NOAA provides weather data. You can see the general information and visualization at http://www.weather.gov/  Specific data products are found at http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/most-popular-data  When you click on a dataset you are interested, there is technical documentation and material to guide you in the use of the data. For example, local climatological data can be found at http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd/QCLCD?prior=N with detailed notes at http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd/qclcdfaq.htm

Answer (score 2):

Besides the NCDC data for forecasts, you can also get pretty detailed meterological information for airports (US and international) in [METAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) format:

- http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/

... but to make use of it, you need to be able to decode the [station codes](http://aviationweather.gov/static/adds/metars/stations.txt) to find airports near the location of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting project -- [open weather map](http://openweathermap.org/API)

Answer (score 2):

[Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org) provides an api with JSON data format. you can parse this data very easy in any modern programming language as python, php or javascript. Open Weather Map has APIs for current weather and even weather forecast from 5 to 14 days.

---

JSON is a simple text based data format than can be converted to arrays or any structured data to access it in your applications. Try RESTClient extension in mozilla firefox to get an idea of how this works if you are new to JSON. You can view any JSON data online, e.g. at [JSON Viewer online](http://jsonformat.com)

Comment: Is this a paid product? I'm looking at it, and it seems to require a paid license.

Comment: 50.000 requests per day are free. Then you'll have to pay. This should be enough for private / home use or small websites.