# Downloadable archive of weather conditions for Europe?

Tags: data-request, weather, europe

Is there a downloadable archive of weather conditions in Europe?

Also, the temperature, humidity, precipitation by location?

So the database would enable, for example, to draw the chart with average temperatures in February or May in Berlin Or Paris.

Comment: Try Global (Surface) Summary of the Day (GSOD) - ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/gsod - very downloadable, very historical, very neat.

Comment: Very very vague question - almost any data set fits to it. You need to specify more: Do you need to see how this parameters vary in time, or you just want long-term average? What time and space resolution do you need?

Comment: Open Weather Map is a pay wall model of data. Not free do not click! Click bait! :o The people who are behind it look at *big business* who have tons of money to waste and not individuals using it. Information is in a *closed* stage still.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts ([ECWMF](http://www.ecmwf.int/)) has a rather impressive data collection available via [batch scripts](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/WEBAPI/Accessing+ECMWF+data+servers+in+batch), [downloadable files](http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/) or even [tailored](http://www.ecmwf.int/products/data/archive/index.html) formats. The first two are freely available (under specific conditions) for non-commercial research but registration is necessary.

Just to give an example, the GRIB dataset lists [4115 parameters](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/GRIB+API) ... including your requested temperature, humidity, precipitation and location (latitude/longitude).

For more casual data retrieval, you might try weather services which focus on specific areas, such as [Yr](http://om.yr.no/verdata/free-weather-data/) from Norway.

Answer (score 8):

You should check out http://worldclim.org/. They have crunched a variety of data sets to produce average temperature and rainfall for each month of the year for most of the earth's surface at a sub-1km resolution. The data is downloadable as raster GIS files that you can load into PostGIS or desktop GIS packages. If you want the underlying data that they used to compile these averages, they have links to some of their sources here:

http://worldclim.org/methods

I've also packaged these up as an API if that's easier for your application:

http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#coordinates2statistics

Answer (score 6):

There are several related opendata.stackexchange related questions to weather in Europe. Here is a compendium of questions/answers:

[Weather radar data for Europe, especially Latvia](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/weather-radar-data-for-europe-latvia-free-download)

[Database with monthly climate/weather data by country](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1796/database-with-monthly-climate-weather-data-by-country)

[What data source for cloud coverage available with forecast and how to parse it?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-data-source-for-cloud-coverage-available-with-forecast-and-how-to-parse-it)

[Historical Weather Forecasts](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/historical-weather-forecasts)

[How might I go about visualising historical temperature CSV data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/how-might-i-go-about-visualising-historical-temperature-csv-data)

[How does one parse weather data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/297/how-does-one-parse-weather-data/310#310)

Answer (score 5):

UK open data is available. See: http://data.gov.uk/dataset/metoffice_uklocs3hr_fc

> hourly observations for approximately 150 UK observing stations, daily
>   site specific and 3 hourly site specific forecasts for approximately
>   5000 UK locations.

Answer (score 3):

There are a large number of datasets covering international areas at the U.S. National Oceanographic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA).  You can see some of the global daily indicators at http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/most-popular-data#ghcn and elsewhere on that page. I think the Global Historical Climatology Network-Daily (GHCN-D) is the data you are seeking.

International indicators of climate change and data collected from many organizations are available at http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/international

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov)

Answer (score 3):

German climate data is available at the [DWD](http://www.dwd.de/bvbw/appmanager/bvbw/dwdwwwDesktop?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=dwdwww_main_book&T82002gsbDocumentPath=Navigation/Oeffentlichkeit/Klima__Umwelt/Klimadaten/kldaten__kostenfrei/Abrufsysteme__Daten__node.html?__nnn=true&switchLang=en&_pageLabel=_dwdwww_klima_umwelt_klimadaten_deutschland).

Answer (score 3):

For worldwide data of over 3000 professional weather stations from the german government authority (the `DWD`) i suggest you [register for a (free) FTP account](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dwd.de%2Fbvbw%2Fappmanager%2Fbvbw%2FdwdwwwDesktop%3F_nfpb%3Dtrue%26_pageLabel%3Ddwdwww_wetter_warnungen%26_state%3Dmaximized%26_windowLabel%3DT174800148261285830600274%26T174800148261285830600274gsbDocumentPath%3DNavigation%25252FOeffentlichkeit%25252FHomepage%25252FWetter__Ihre__Website%25252Fftp-Zugriff__node.html%25253F__nnn%25253Dtrue&ei=TpY9U4KlJIjCtAbn8oCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHOLk7rKtAPKssMth9laabtOoOM-A&sig2=FjNI3LgM1Nif8lMEkN0sQg&bvm=bv.64125504,d.Yms) with them to pull it directly.

Although those are only 125 "free" stations in Europe, in particular for Germany it is the best-validated data available.

Answer (score 2):

Forecast.io has a nice API for weather data.

https://developer.forecast.io/

Another nice resource if you want climate predictions is from the World Bank

http://data.worldbank.org/developers/climate-data-api

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org). There are more than 40.000 weather stations around the globe and an excellent coverage in europe. They provide a very good API for free and also 5 to 14 day forecast mechanisms.

Comment: Good site, but does it have archive of weather (historical data)? I can't find it.

Comment: The [historical data is available via their API](http://openweathermap.org/history)

Answer (score 2):

try at weather underground. and here is a random search for historical data about Berlin
http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EDDT/2014/9/20/CustomHistory.html?dayend=20&monthend=9&yearend=2015&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=

Comment: OK, history beginning in 1996 ...