# Historic weather data - With clouds resolution

Tags: data-request, geospatial, weather

I'm looking for a dataset that holds hourly/daily cloud coverage rates at different heights.
I need the data to a geo reference too, preferably United States data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: is this useful? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/837/1511 (in general, if you search clouds, there are a couple other similar questions here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What data source for cloud coverage available with forecast and how to parse it?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-data-source-for-cloud-coverage-available-with-forecast-and-how-to-parse-it)

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful. METAR data specifically contains cloud coverage at different elevations, but I don't know how much historic METAR data is available for free (I believe all of it is available paid).