# Is there any free weather database that one could use for correlations in business intelligence software?

Tags: data-request, weather

I would like to see how big is the correlation between weather and visits to our website, but I can't seem to find any database that has option of downloading chosen datasets. Any ideas?

To be specific I am talking about Poland / Europe.

Comment: This data request seems to broad. What specific weather parameters are you looking for? How will it be used in your BI software?

Comment: Temperature and rain. I wanted to see how big is the possitive correlation between above average temperature/rain and visits to our website (or at least try to do that).

Comment: Could you please update your question accordingly to make it clear what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Also, have you already looked at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/365/70?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two resources:

1. https://developer.forecast.io/ (free for low use, then paid after that)
2. http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/#t=secondTabLink

The NOAA data is used by a developer in Chicago to [explore the correlation between weather and crime](http://crime.static-eric.com/).

Comment: welcome on opendata stack exchange. I have moved your link to your answer directly. You can edit, enrich your answer any time. It is also appreciated when user disclose when they are developers of a tool or application they promote here.

Comment: For accessing NOAA data you can also use Microsoft's Azure Open Datasets - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/open-datasets/catalog/noaa-integrated-surface-data/?tab=data-access#AzureNotebooks

Answer (score 3):

Wunderground has an API with historical weather ([link](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history)). You can get 500 free API requests per day, so you have to be patient if you want to go back years. I found for my location a detailed daily history going back to 1997 (high temp, low temp, mean temp, precipitation amount, plus way more).

**update**: the reason I post this now is that the Wunderground API includes international weather (and not just US).

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to Chris Gansen for Portland, OR. I downloaded the crime datasets from Portland's open data portal (www.civicapps.org) and the corresponding weather data from NOAA.

I then created a new CSV dataset from the originals where I added fields for temperature mean, percipitation and snowfall, and posted them for other developers to use:

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude/civicapps/civicapps.crime_incident_data.csv

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer. But I recently had the same question. During my research I found this site:

[Meteostat](https://dev.meteostat.net/)

They describe themself as

> Meteostat is an open platform which provides free access to historical weather and climate data.

There's a own python library and a JSON API available (2022-07-18).

I found that for my locations of interest the last few months (~4) aren't available.

For all the ones looking for a simple and free way to get historical weather data this is the best source I found.