# I need data set for climate changes in San Diego?

Tags: data-request, weather

If any of you guys could find accurate data sets for temperature and several other parameters for climate change in San Diego please share the link. Please share any other accurate datasets available for san diego city.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Historical weather data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4242/historical-weather-data)

Comment: I vote to leave it open, This is more specific area that the question you link to @philshem and might lead to different and useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some Python scripts that can be adapted for that. You just need an API key from wunderground.

https://github.com/joshmalina/pollution/blob/master/Build_historical_weather_data.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

For Us climate data select the following link:
Link:
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov
1.Next select Data access
2.quick link
3.Integrated Surface Data, Hourly, Global.
4.select ISD/CDO
5.continue with advance options.
6.select country.
7.slect state.
8.select location.
9.select required parameters you need.
10.Then select the date from when you want to analyze the data.
11. you would be getting data within the mentioned time.

The data provided is free and is helpful. They have data hourly and daily. Hope this would be helpful.