# Free Archive of Africa weather data

Tags: data-request, weather, africa

Is there any archive for Africa weather station data? What i know exists is the [GHCN](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/quick-links#ghcn) database and other gridded sources.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with ISD as well? ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/

Comment: What kind of time period are you looking for? Does this answer help? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4243/1511

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Historical weather data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4242/historical-weather-data)

Comment: Check this answer for getting Africa weather station data from NOAA via Google BigQuery: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7583/11083