# Historical weather forecast API

Tags: data-request, api, weather, historical, europe

For a college project I need historical weather **forecasts** for Europe up to 14 days for 2015 and 2016. The last two days I was desperately searching for APIs with such data, but usually there is just observed data for historical dates.

I know this question got asked a lot in here but I cant find any answer which fits my requirements.

Does anyone knows a good source where I can get these kind of data like described above? Where I can send a request with a **date range** in the past and some latitude and longitudes and get the weather forecast up to 14 days for each day in **date range**?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried Google BigQuery?

GBQ has now loaded climate data worldwide from the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Association (NOAA) from over 9,000 weather stations. The data includes 2015 and 2016.

You can query the climate data set using SQL. This queries 14 days of max temperatures (tested just now):

```
SELECT year, mo, da, temp FROM [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2015] WHERE year = '2015' AND mo = '01' AND INTEGER(da) > 7 AND INTEGER(da) < 21
```

Here are a few columns from the data dictionary:

```
stn     STRING  NULLABLE    Station number (WMO/DATSAV3 number) for the location
wban    STRING  NULLABLE    WBAN number where applicable--this is the historical "Weather Bureau Air Force Navy" number - with WBAN being the acronym
year    STRING  NULLABLE    The year
mo      STRING  NULLABLE    The month
da      STRING  NULLABLE    The day
temp    FLOAT   NULLABLE    Mean temperature for the day in degrees Fahrenheit to tenths. Missing = 9999.9
```

BigQuery allows 1 terabyte of queries for free each month.

Comment: But again, this is just actual, observed data and not the weather forecast.

Answer (score 2):

Have at a look at [this post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/365/downloadable-archive-of-weather-conditions-for-europe?lq=1), as it might answer your questions.

Alternatively I know that historic data can be requested from the [UK's MetOffice](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/climate-historic/#?tab=climateHistoric) as long as it is non commercial purposes, but this is only UK data, which may not be sufficient for you.

Answer (score -1):

openweathermap.org provides historical forecasts by location for the past 3 years. You purchase the data by location and 3 years of historical forecasts that you can download immediately is available for $45 dollars I believe. I searched long and hard for somebody that provided historical forecasts. Everyone provides historical weather but not the forecasts. Even the US government through NOAA starts purging forecasts after 90 days.