# Get Historic Temperature Data by GPS and Timestamp Using R

Tags: api, weather, historical, programming, xml

I have a dataset:

```
ID       Time                Lat        Long   
a    2016-06-01 10:35:26    41.79925   -71.33052  
a    2016-06-01 10:35:57    41.80174   -71.33307
a    2016-06-01 10:37:30    41.79259   -71.31087 
a    2016-06-01 19:21:34    41.65239   -70.95343  
a    2016-06-01 19:22:36    41.65485   -70.97474  
a    2016-06-01 19:23:07    41.65504   -70.98545
```

I want to get hourly temperature data(assume temperature remain the same during hour) for each point based on GPS and timestamp, since the data are consecutive vehicle trajectory data. The expected outcome would be:

```
ID       Time                Lat        Long       TempHourly
a    2016-06-01 10:35:26    41.79925   -71.33052     70
a    2016-06-01 10:35:57    41.80174   -71.33307     70
a    2016-06-01 10:37:30    41.79259   -71.31087     70 
a    2016-06-01 19:21:34    41.65239   -70.95343     65
a    2016-06-01 19:22:36    41.65485   -70.97474     65
a    2016-06-01 19:23:07    41.65504   -70.98545     65
```

Is there any free APIs that I can get accessed to fetch the temperature data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it is unclear. What do you mean with *hourly temperature data*? How can the example you give return equal temperatures for different locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend trying `rnoaa` https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rnoaa/ - It's an interface to many different data sources from NOAA.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = letters[1:6], 
  time = c("2016-06-01 10:35:26", "2016-06-01 10:35:57", "2016-06-01 10:37:30",
           "2016-06-01 19:21:34", "2016-06-01 19:22:36", "2016-06-01 19:23:07"),
  latitude = c(41.79925, 41.80174, 41.79259, 41.65239, 41.65485, 41.65504),
  longitude = c(-71.33052, -71.33307, -71.31087, -70.95343, -70.97474, -70.98545),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Using `rnoaa` you can access data from Integrated Surface Data (ISD) which has hourly data, but not sub-hourly

```
library(rnoaa)
```

For each point you can do something like:

```
x <- isd_stations_search(lat = df$latitude[1], lon = df$longitude[1], radius = 10)
dat <- isd(usaf = x$usaf[1], wban = x$wban[1], year = 2016)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat %>% 
  filter(date == "20160601", time == paste0(hour(df$time[1]), "00")) %>% 
  select(starts_with("temperature"))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#> temperature temperature_quality temperature_dewpoint temperature_dewpoint_quality
#> <chr>               <chr>                <chr>                        <chr>
#> 1       +0197                   1                +9999                            9
```

ISD data is not cleaned up so e.g., `temperature` has to be divided by 10, so `197/10 = 19.7`

Comment: Thanks for the help, wondering what's the quota limits, since I have quite a lot points to query.

Comment: `rnoaa::isd()` is pulling from an FTP server, so it's not an API, no limits.

Comment: Great to know, reading the package file now. Will try it soon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd say, the date in variable dat is of form '2016-06-01".

Comment: for dat %>%>..., I get 
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "isd"

Comment: @poitroae please open an issue here https://github.com/ropensci/rnoaa/issues

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, latitiude/longitude with resolution to 5 decimals places corresponds to 1.1 meter ([reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674)). I would imagine that the first step would to to find the nearest weather station, based on each lat/long pairs. Unless your geo-locations are coincidentally weather stations, you can't get super-resolution weather measurements (without computational modeling).

---

As for an API with historical data, [Wunderground](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs) is often suggested on this site ([example](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4243/1511)). For limited requests there is a free quota. Here is documentation for that [endpoint](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history). Note that the historical weather measurement does have a timestamp but is not an timeseries with more than daily resolution. You have some other temperatures such as min/max that you can also use.

Another endpoint is ([geolookup](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/geolookup)), which will:

> Returns the city name, zip code / postal code, latitude-longitude coordinates and nearby personal weather stations.

The specific URI would look like this

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/geolookup/q/37.776289,-122.395234.json
```

and the details are in this screenshot

[image]

---

R has a package called [rwunderground](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rwunderground/index.html).

> Tools for getting historical weather information and forecasts from wunderground.com. Historical weather and forecast data includes, but is not limited to, temperature, humidity, windchill, wind speed, dew point, heat index. Additionally, the weather underground weather API also includes information on sunrise/sunset, tidal conditions, satellite/webcam imagery, weather alerts, hurricane alerts and historical record high/low temperatures.

Another is [weatherData](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/weatherData/weatherData.pdf) (pdf)

> Functions that help in fetching weather data from websites. Given a location and a date range, these functions help fetch weather data (temperature, pressure etc.) for any weather related analysis.

---

---

Another option would be getting the data from [Google Big Query](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7583/1511) and corresponding R-package [bigrquery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/README.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information provided! Another question, how to get weather station ID based on GPS coordinates?

Comment: I added an updated (see above)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to all those references and sources, it really saves me a lot of time searching.