# what was the weather in red rock, nv March 14, 2016

Tags: weather

What was the weather in Red Rock, Nevada on March 14, 2016? Specifically, what were the wind gusts?

Comment: Try wunderground.com for recent data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Historical weather data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4242/historical-weather-data)

Answer (score 3):

If you are less than 7 days past a date in question, NOAA's weather service maintains a history of wind speeds etc. available through [http://www.wrh.noaa.gov](http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/).

For instance, history at the weather station in Kyle Canyon (near Red Rock) is located [here](http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mesowest/getobext.php?wfo=vef&sid=KYCN2&num=168&raw=0&dbn=m).

I've had great luck emailing the local NOAA administrators for access to data as far back as three years (I've never asked for anything more than that).  Click 'contact us' once you narrow in on a particular weather station and follow the lead.   It has been a while, and I believe the 3-year dataset I asked for came in a *.dat format, so there was some conversion involved, but I can not verify if they still deliver data that way.  If you need help converting you can reach out to the greater SO community or contact me directly.