# National Scale (contiguous US) weather data set for 1980 - 2010

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, weather

Does anyone know of any national weather datasets that cover the contiguous US for the period 1980 to 2011?  I need gridded values, preferably with a grid size (resolution) of 1 km x 1 km up to (maybe) 10 km x 10 km.  I don't want point sites nor do I want to spatially average between point sites - I'll take datasets where that is already done, but I don't have the skill set to do that myself.  I know about NOAA's NCDC, but they don't seem to produce any gridded datasets.  Weather Underground doesn't seem to produce any gridded data sets.

I need hourly values, but can probably deal with daily values, of Temp and Precip at a minimum, but ideally also need windspeed, atmospheric pressure, humidity, etc.

I haven't had much like finding any other than Global Circulation Model outputs. And picking the right one of those can be confusing.

Comment: have you taken a look at the comments and answers in this similar question? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/historical-weather-forecasts  ... if you don't believe your question is similar, it might be good to mention how it is different so it isn't potentially down voted by others.

Comment: I think the difference is shown now?

Comment: Yes... but unfortunately all the resources I know of (all of which were mentioned in the links provided) do not meet your pretty specific specs. Perhaps you would have more luck with accepting a broader type of data and ask for help creating the grid format you specify.

Comment: The NARR data set offers most of the variables I am looking for, but I would like to stay away from GCM outputs.

Answer (score 2):

this set doesn't get to 2010 but does start 20 years prior (1960), and its gridded:
http://www.columbia.edu/~ws2162/dailyData.html

Comment: This data set looks promising.  I'll have to investigate further before marking this suggestions as an answer.  And of course I hope others contribute suggestions too.