# Looking for historical weather forecasts

Tags: data-request, weather, historical, internet

I am looking to write a report about the accuracy of weather forecasts. I have already found several source that provides data for actual weather in different locations, but I am having difficulty finding data about weather forecasts in the past. I would like to find a site that has this data available.

Comment: Have you looked at these questions? — https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=historical+weather+forecast

Comment: Most of those answers provide links that don't work or that are irrelevant.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/historical-weather-forecasts and/or https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9639/historical-weather-forecast-compared-to-actual-weather may or may not be helpful.

Comment: All the answers provide dead links.

Comment: The first answer on the first page mentioned by Barry mentions *NOAA / National Weather Service has an archive from the Weather Prediction Center*. Google that phrase and you find the updated page. I guess that goes for many more of those 'dead links' you mention. You can even contribute to this site by updating those answers with the new links.