# Does anybody know how to retrieve historical forecasted weather data? I am looking for forecasted data, not actual data

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, weather

Most websites only provides historical actual weather data (e.g. the observed temperature on March 5 2015 was ...). I am specifically looking for forecasted weather data (e.g. the forecasted temperature on March 5 2015 for the next day was...).

Does anybody who came across such datasets? The geographical area I am looking for is The Netherlands.

Comment: See https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/historical-weather-forecasts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Historical Weather Forecasts](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/historical-weather-forecasts)