# Weather radar data for Europe, especially Latvia

Tags: data-request, data.gov, weather, europe

I would like to ask if there is a homepage where I can get weather radar data for Europe territory for free. I have looked in the internet, but can't find them. I will be very glad if someone can help me. (It would be ideal to get the rainfall or precipitation data for Latvia.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloadable archive of weather conditions for Europe?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/365/downloadable-archive-of-weather-conditions-for-europe)

Comment: Anastasios Ventouris, I am seeking for radar data, but on the most sites I saw only satellite data...

Comment: This data is from Satellites http://openweathermap.org/?

Comment: If I understand correctly this data is from meteorlogic stations

Comment: I have removed the "close" vote and I wait to see if anyone else has data from radar. Since I don't know anything about it.

Comment: Most of these sites change over time which is likely why your getting *no parameters found* error as whatever address it once linked to is no longer there on THEIR end of the server.

Answer (score 2):

Weather radar data specific to Latvia can be found using [NOAA's Radar Data tool](https://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/map/viewer/#app=cdo&cfg=radar&theme=radar&display=nexrad).  Just enter "Republic of Latvia" in the search box and you're off and running.

There are a large number of datasets covering international areas at the U.S. National Oceanographic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA), which maps some of the [global daily indicators](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/most-popular-data#ghcn). The Global Historical Climatology Network-Daily (GHCN-D) is the data you are seeking.

[International indicators of climate change](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/international) and data collected from many organizations are available as well.

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov)

Comment: I tried to get data, you have adviced. But when I used[link](https://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/map/viewer/#app=cdo&cfg=radar&theme=radar&display=nexrad) after I enter "Republic of Latvia" and then select by rectangle. I get error message "No features founded". Am I doing something wrong here? Also when I use [link](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search?datasetid=GHCND) I also get error message: "Sorry, but no items match the search as specified". Is there some shance to get data like [link](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/samples/GHCND_sample_pdf.pdf) but for Latvia?

Answer (score 2):

**Lativa Government's General Statistics** provides this data in downloadable datasets on a monthly basis. It goes back to Jan 2012.

http://www.csb.gov.lv/en/statistikas-temas/metodologija/weather-conditions-and-air-quality-latvia-38299.html

**The European Climate Assessment & Dataset (ECAD),** Royal Netherlands Meteorological Institute (KNMI) collects weather data from 62 countries and makes some datasets available for non-commercial use.

*Today, ECA&D is receiving data from  63 participants for  62 countries and the ECA dataset contains 37491 series of observations for  12 elements at  7862 meteorological stations throughout Europe and the Mediterranean (see Daily data > Data dictionary). 61% of these daily series can be downloaded from this website for non-commercial research and education. Participation to ECA&D is open to anyone maintaining daily station data. If you want to join please contact us. See our data policy for more details.*

http://eca.knmi.nl/