# Open alternative to weatherbase.com

Tags: data-request, weather

Does anyone know of an open alternative to [weatherbase](http://weatherbase.com)?  I'm looking for what's [listed here as "Average Temperature"](http://www.weatherbase.com/weather/weather.php3?s=42287&cityname=Havana-Cuba). I'm looking for monthly averages for a city, hopefully for as many cities as possible. [This from NOAA](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/normals/1981-2010/products/temperature/mly-tavg-normal.txt) is perfect but only for US weather stations. As for time range, I care more about it being more recent as compared to backed by more years of data.

Comment: related : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/365/263 ; http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/297/263

Comment: Describing reasons why you are looking for an other data source will help other to better understand your expectations. Why weatherbase doesn't works for you?

Comment: @magdmartin I pretty much was scared away by the fact that there was only a licensing link and no obvious way to just get a dump of their data. If that's not the case, weatherbase has exactly what I need.

Comment: @Chris : so that we don't have to go and look into what weatherbase is, could you give something more specific about what it is from their data that you're interested in?  Do you only need current data?  How far back does it need to go?  Is monthly average in terms of 'average January temperature' or 'January 2012 average temp'?  Is global cities all continents, or just a subset, like Europe & Asia?  If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Joe Sorry about that! I'm looking for what's listed here as "Average Temperature" http://www.weatherbase.com/weather/weather.php3?s=42287&cityname=Havana-Cuba So monthly averages for a city, hopefully for as many cities as possible. This: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/normals/1981-2010/products/temperature/mly-tavg-normal.txt from NOAA is perfect but only for US weather stations. As for time range, I care more about it being more recent as compared to backed by more years of data.

Comment: @Chris Would you mind working your last comment into the question? That way you would make it easier for people to see at first glance what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [NASA GISS Surface Temperature Analysis](http://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/station_data/)? Although they have station-oriented timeseries, global coverage seems quite good and they provide monthly average temperatures globally for a ridiculously long time: [random sample of a station dataset in Africa (1946-2012)](http://data.giss.nasa.gov/tmp/gistemp/STATIONS/tmp_109646560000_14_0/station.txt):

```
YEAR    JAN    FEB  ...   DEC
1946   24.8   25.9  ...  26.4
1947   26.1   27.3  ...  25.3
1948   25.8   27.4  ...  25.7
...
2010   25.9   28.0  ... 999.9
2011  999.9  999.9  ... 999.9
2012  999.9  999.9  ... 999.9
```

Major cities tend to have one or multiple stations with identical name nearby. Documentation of their data processing is naturally very good. *(Meh: the sample station I picked seems to be plagued by missing values [`999.9`] recently.)*

Comment: I actually ended up using the (GHCN dataset from noaa)[http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/ghcnm/] which I think the GISS is related to somehow? The app I built is here: http://p-seventy-two.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you are after weather data besides the US and need UK data, you can use the 3 hourly reports from [data.gov.uk](http://data.gov.uk/metoffice-data-archive) although historically it goes back only to December 2011 and we don't provide a data API.

The interface gives access to three datasets, hourly observations for approximately 150 UK observing stations, daily site specific and 3 hourly site specific forecasts for approximately 5000 UK locations.

You can also get it with a data API from [Windows Azure Marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/0f2cba12-e5cf-4c6d-83c9-83114d44387a) or the [Met Office data point](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint) (free but requires email signup)

Answer (score 3):

Wish I saw this sooner, but we field requests for data all the time. For non-commercial or academic, we're always happy to help. Feel free to drop me an email from the website.

Comment: Thanks for joining Open Data SE! Could you please add information to your answer regarding your affiliation with Weatherbase? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org) already? It's free and has an excellent API. We are using OWM because it has a great worldwide coverage of weather stations (more than 40.000).

Answer (score 1):

I have found http://www.wunderground.com/ to be excellent. Great API and good coverage.

Weather Underground provides weather information based on personal weather stations, airports and other open sources. It provides current weather, forecasts and historic data. Great search facilities and a very easy to use API.

It is open as in 'free' for low use. Open as in 'community sourced'.

Comment: good suggestion. Perhaps you can expand a bit so there's better documentation on this option.

Comment: Wunderground - Weather Underground provides weather information based on personal weather stations, airports and other open sources. It provides current weather, forecasts and historic data. Great search facilities and a very easy to use API.

Comment: But do they actually provide [Open Data](http://opendefinition.org/)? As far as I can tell, Weather Underground looks rather commercial. Their [API Terms of Service](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html) don't mention the word "open" either ...

Comment: Well, it is open as in 'free' for low use. Open as in 'community sourced'.